# What is the overline above the letters I don't understand how to find the elements of this symmetric difference.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, notation

Assume the universal set $\,\mathcal U = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}$. If $A = \{1, 2, 4, 6, 7\}, B = \{1, 2, 4, 6\}$ and $C = \{1, 3, 4, 7\}$, what is $\overline{A}⊕\overline{B ⊕ C}$ ?

What does is a universal set? And what is the difference between not having the overline above the letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overline means complement: $$\overline{A}=\mathcal{U} \setminus A = \{3,5,8\}.$$

Comment: so the difference of the universal set and set A?

Comment: Yes, I gave a little more detail just now.

Comment: Then would the second part of the difference be U ∖ (B⊕C). So first I have to find the symmetric difference B⊕C then do regular set difference?

Comment: Yes, that is the most straightforward approach.